# Runtime error: OfficeExtension.Promise is not defined

Tags: office-js

I am trying to use promises in an Outlook add-in. And I am trying this per documentation:

```
    return Promise.resolve(function () {
        console.log("in promise");
    }).then(function () {
        console.log("in promise then");
    });
```

Promise.resolve() is also showing up in the context help. However, when I run it, I get a runtime error that “Promise is undefined.” I am running 1.1.0.10 of office.js and am pointed at the repository:

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, when I type in “new OfficeExtension.”, Promise is not listed. I only see what I guess is an interface “IPromise.”

Is Promises available in the current release? Or, should I be pointing to a different repository?

Answer (score 3):

[ **NOTE: UPDATED May 2018** ]

There are several issues here:

1. If you are using `Promise` as is, you need some sort of polyfill that patches the global `window.Promise` object on IE 11 and earlier (which is what is used on the Desktop for Office Add-ins). An example of one such library is "core-js", available at https://github.com/zloirock/core-js
2. OfficeExtension.Promise is only available in ExcelApi 1.2, WordApi 1.2, or OneNote 1.1.  BUT **(updated May 2018)**, we offer an alias to the same thing on **`Office.Promise`**, which all hosts can now use, including Outlook.
3. The IntelliSense (both the VSDOC that gets silently downloaded for JavaScript IntelliSense in Visual Studio, and the [DefinitelyTyped definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/office-js/office-js.d.ts) for TypeScript) is common to all hosts.  Hence you are seeing `OfficeExtension` (and you would see `Word` or `Excel` as well), even though those would not be supported at runtime for an Outlook add-in.  *(Note, I am not sure if "Office.Promise" is actually showing up in VSDoc/D.ts, it was only added very very recently.  I'll make a note to add it soon, if it's not there already)*.

Comment: Hello Michael! As far as I know the OfficeExtension.Promise is already available in ExcelApi 1.1 and WordApi 1.1. Can you tell me which Update from Windows Update is needed for Office 2016?

Comment: See my update to the answer.  As of just a few days ago, you can use "Office.Promise", which is available on all hosts.  Or you can use a Polyfill, as per #1